# Why isn't my infopath data connection returning all results in the document library?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm running Infopath 2010 in windows 7. But I'm saving in the format "Infopath 2007 filler form" in order to publish to our sharepoint 2007. I'm trying to create an auto numbering system on a document library.

In order to do this I use a form submit rule to set project_num to the maximum value of project_num in my document library plus one. This works sometimes. When it doesn't work, the "max(@product num)" function returns the project_num value of a seemingly arbitrary document(102, out of 129). When I deleted this document, I got back a value of 103.

So I created a new form, set up a new rule on a 2010 form and got the right result. But when I save it as a 2007 form and fix up the data connections, I get 103 back.

All items in the library have the project_num field are filled in. I tried migrating the document library by saving it as a template in sharepoint. But the new library produces the same results.

Comment: I've resolved the problem by changing the item limit in the default library view in sharepoint from 100 to 2147483647

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the problem by changing the item limit in the default library view in sharepoint from 100 to 2147483647